# python(x86_64) tensorflow install error (Could not find a version...)

Tags: python, tensorflow, 64-bit

**Summary**
Setup python3.7(64bit) and `pip install tensorflow` then, I've got the message, you may hate.

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
>       No matching distribution found for tensorflow
>   As many person have been see.

as many person have been seen. what's wrong? :(

**Success:** old command
I found while searching... and this command was worked.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

very old version though...

**Tries**: Install path

First, Python installed `c:\program file\Python37` And after meet the message, re-install to `%USERPROFILE%\Appdata\Local\Program\Python37` yeah, nothing changed.

Comment: **Self Solve** Use 3.6.x